# How can I build a 2D Array from array stack, selecting non-NAN along third dimension?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have *n* 2D numpy arrays, that are stacked along the third dimension. Each array contains `np.nan` values. I want to construct a new 2D array out of the stack. Each value in it should be the first *non np.nan* value along the third dimension.

To illustrate, think of the *top view* of the 2D stack and imagine each `np.nan` as transparant.

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3],
              [4,5,np.nan],
              [7,8,9],
              [10,11,12]])
b = np.array([[np.nan,21,np.nan],
              [23,24,25],
              [26,27,28],
              [29, 30,31]])
c = np.array([[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
              [43,np.nan,np.nan],
              [46,np.nan,48],
              [49, 50, 51]])
stack = np.stack([a, b, c], axis=0)
for d in [2,1]:
    if d == 2:
        fill = stack[d, :,:]
    arr = np.where(np.isnan(stack[d,:,:]), stack[d-1,:,:], fill)
    fill = arr
```

This illustrates the problem and delivers desired result, see below. Note that `c` is given highest priority. This is intentional.

```py
>>> arr
array([[ 1., 21.,  3.],
       [43., 24., 25.],
       [46., 27., 48.],
       [49., 50., 51.]])
```

I was wondering if this can be solved more efficiently and without a loop? Perhaps using `np.isnan(stack)` and [np.select](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)?

Comment: why `d==2` should be in priority? that's manual constructing

Comment: You're right, that's not pretty. Hence my question.  I see now I also forgot a line in the example: `fill = arr`. This sets the `fill` array for the `True` condition in `np.where` to the array that's just been created. In the first iteration (`d==2`), the `fill` array equals the top-level array of the stacked array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
arr = np.stack([a, b, c], axis=0)
arr = np.flip(arr, axis=0)
idx = np.argmax(~np.isnan(arr), axis=0)
out = np.take_along_axis(arr, idx[None, ...],  axis=0).squeeze()
print(out)
```

It gives:

```
[[ 1. 21.  3.]
 [43. 24. 25.]
 [46. 27. 48.]
 [49. 50. 51.]]
```